# Deploying Custom Metadatatype and apex class using that custom metadata type

Tags: json, change-set, custom-metadata

I have an apex class which is exposed as a rest API, It sends field value of a custom metadata type in response.
My response string is like this -

```
    string respString = '{"success":'+true+',"customMetVal":'+JSON.Serialize(customMetVal[0])+',
                          "account":'+JSON.Serialize(account[0])+'}'
```

while testing this class in sandbox, I get complete code coverage but when I try validating in my production org, I get this error:

```
System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('E' (code 69)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]
```

I need some insights on what I am doing wrong, Is this response that I am sending from apex class not right or do I need to deploy custom metadata type before deploying apex class or anything else which I am not able to see.
Also, in my custom metadata type, I have a field which contains value like this -

```
"Custom_Field__c": "Hi! Greetings, “We can’t help everyone, but everyone can help someone” (Ronald Reagan)."
```

Is the JSON exception because of this field value? If so then why I am not getting error while testing in sandbox?

Comment: what is included in your change set that you are validating? You'll need to include your custom metadata types in the same change set as the code.

Comment: The deployment needs to include apex + custom object for the MDT + the custom metadata record(s); that said, testmethods should mock MDT records via a Selector pattern) and not rely on org MDT values

Comment: @cropredy how do we mock MDT can you provide some insights please, I am new to salesforce development

Comment: see this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111375/insert-custom-metadata-for-unit-test/184001#184001) for one idea - basically, you need to use a separate object (selector) to query the MDT and at run time, the testmethod injects a mock selector to return known values to the caller. See also Lightning Enterprise Architecture 3rd edition book chapter on unit testing for another perspective